# ``request for member ‘tv_sec’ in something not a structure or union`` System call linux

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, system-calls

I am trying to add a new system call that displays some information about processes. I created a new struct named processinf that contains parts of the process information I want to display. Here is the processinf code defined in types.h

```
struct processinf
{
    pid_t pid;
    long state;
    char *comm;
    time_t st;
};
```

Syscall:

```
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <linux/linkage.h>
#include <linux/pid.h>
#include <asm/uaccess.h>
#include <linux/types.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>
#include <linux/time.h>


asmlinkage long proc_inf(pid_t pid, struct processinf *p)
{
    struct task_struct *task = pid_task(find_vpid(pid), PIDTYPE_PID);
    p->pid = task->pid;
    strcpy(p->comm, task->comm);
    p->state = task->state;
    p->st = task->start_time.tv_sec;


    copy_to_user(p, p, sizeof(struct processinf));
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to build the kernel by using make I get the following error:
**error: request for member ‘tv_sec’ in something not a structure or union
     p->st = task->start_time.tv_sec;**
What am I missing here?

Comment: Likely `p->comm` is not pointing to any allocated space.  Try `strcpy(p->comm, task->comm);` --> `p->comm = strdup(task->comm);`  `copy_to_user(p, p, sizeof(struct processinf));` looks dodgy too - copying to self?

Comment: Find the definition of the `struct task_struct`; in there, you'll find a `start_time` member.  That `start_time` member isn't a `struct timespec` or `struct timeval` (two standard POSIX types that contain a `tv_sec` member).  It might be a pointer to one of those types, in which case you need `->` instead of `.`, or it might be a different type (`time_t` is a non-structure type, for example).  With the definition of `struct task_struct`, solving this is trivial; without it, solving it is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

The nature of the question and the code presented strongly suggest you are unprepared to do kernel work even at this capacity at this time. If you are just learning on your own, I strongly suggest you take a step back on focus on userspace. If this is a college assignment, which it seems it is, I have to ask what materials were you provided with and in particular where you took code samples from. Since questions with very same mistakes and similar nature of the task at hand show up a lot, I suspect someone just gives out very bad learning materials.

There are 2 comments added below the question. I find them to be of low quality if not straight up harmful.

The first one rightfully points out that copy_to_user(p, p, ..); is likely wrong. However, it contains an extremely puzzling statement suggesting "strcpy(p->comm, task->comm); --> p->comm = strdup(task->comm);".

The second one suggests taking look at task_struct to figure out what the type of start_time is. A much better thing to do instead is to look for already existing code reading the field.

None of these considerations matter though as the code is fundamentally flawed, but said comments fail to address the issue.

Let's take a look at the code:

```
asmlinkage long proc_inf(pid_t pid, struct processinf *p)
```

First a minor note that 'p' is often used as a name for pointers to threads, therefore it is somewhat confusing to see it like this here. I suggest renaming to e.g. 'pi'.

```
{
    struct task_struct *task = pid_task(find_vpid(pid), PIDTYPE_PID);
```

The linux kernel is a heavily multithreaded project. In such an environment accessing various objects requires following certain rules. Doing so guarantees you read data in a consistent state and the target object is not going to get suddely freed. Failure to follow the rules easily leads to crashes under sufficient load. This should be obvious from concurrent programming lessons you hopefully had.

In particular, threads can be created and destroyed (and freed) at any time. Therefore if you are to access a random thread, you need a way to ensure it is not getting freed until you don't need it anymore.

The code as presented has to be wrong. Either the task is returned pinned in some manner and you fail to unpin it at the end, or the task is not pinned whatsoever and you failed to meet requirements of calling pid_task in the first place. It so happens the latter is the case. Particular requirements are left as an exercise for the reader.

```
    p->pid = task->pid;
```

It is possible that the task was not found and the pointer is NULL.

'p' is a pointer provided by userspace. Access of this manner is a security and reliability threat. Consider what happens when the user passes an address of something within the kernel or is garbage. Also it will straight up not work in several cases (e.g. SMAP or architectures which have the kernel address space split from userspace).

Things of this manner should have been covered at the beginning of the course.

```
    strcpy(p->comm, task->comm);
```

Basic programming problem. Similarly to previous cases, you should check how existing consumers access the field and that would lead you to '
get_task_comm'. Further, you would find that the 'comm' field is TASK_COMM_LEN characters long and it likely makes perfect sense to modify the structure to have an array of the size instead of a pointer.

```
    p->state = task->state;
    p->st = task->start_time.tv_sec;
```

A small weirdness comes from the disparity in naming -- all other fields have names consistent with what is found in task_struct, but this one diverges. It is also very unclear what is the problem with figuring out the type of the field and how to access it.

One great tool you are looking for is "grep".

```
    copy_to_user(p, p, sizeof(struct processinf));
```

Now this line makes things even weirder. If you are aware you have to copy stuff out, and to memory pointed to by p, why were you dereferencing 'p' previously? As was mentioned by a comment, this clearly has to be wrong.

What you need is a local variable of type struct processinf, fill that in, and then copy it out.

Finally, copy_to_user can easily fail and the error should be propagated back to the user as opposed to getting ignored.

```
    return 0;
}
```